# How do I pass a time from android timepicker to the edit text field that was just clicked?

Tags: android, android-edittext, timepicker

So on a page of my app, there are two EditText fields (editEarliestDepart and editLatestDepart).

I'd like two things to happen:

1. When a user clicks one of them, I'd like for a TimePicker fragment dialog to appear. After a user sets the time, the values will get passed to, and displayed in, the EditText field that was just selected.
2. When user sets "editLatestDepart", ensure that "editLatestDepart" always comes after "editEarliestDepart".

Can anyone please help me figure this out? I've been trying for days, and it's driving me mad.

Thank you,

Kevin

The Activity that calls the Timepicker fragment dialog.

```
public class NewDriverSetupTime extends FragmentActivity implements TimePickedListener   {

    String pickerHour, pickerMinute;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_driver_setup_time);

        //create on click listener for earliest depart
        EditText earliestDepart = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editEarliestDepart);
        earliestDepart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerDialogFragment();
                newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");   
            }
        });

        //create on click listener for latest depart
        EditText latestDepart = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editLatestDepart);
        latestDepart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerDialogFragment();
                newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onTimePicked(Calendar time) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // display the selected time in the clicked editview

    }
}
```

Here is the actual Fragment code

```
public class TimePickerDialogFragment extends DialogFragment
    implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    private TimePickedListener mListener;

    @Override

    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }
     @Override
     public void onAttach(Activity activity)  {
         // when the fragment is initially shown (i.e. attached to the activity), cast the activity to the callback interface type
         super.onAttach(activity);
         try
         {
             mListener = (TimePickedListener) activity;
         }
         catch (ClassCastException e)
         {
             throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement " + TimePickedListener.class.getName());
         }

     }

     public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

        // when the time is selected, send it to the activity via its callback interface method
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
            c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

            mListener.onTimePicked(c);

        }
     public static interface TimePickedListener
        {
            public void onTimePicked(Calendar time);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

this may help u...

in onclick method ....

```
Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
        mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
                edittext.setText( selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute);
            }
        }, hour, minute, true);//Yes 24 hour time
        mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
        mTimePicker.show();
```

Comment: i'm sorry, but this is not very useful to me without an explanation. i'm very new to android programming. so please explain the solution to me like i am five.

Comment: First of all write on click method to text view and in on click method of textview write the above code , such that when u click on text view a time picker rise and the time changed by you will be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is design a fragment which has your TimePicker inside.  Then inside of this fragment have a callback to your main activity which fills the main activities EditText.

You can find information on using callbacks here:

[Communicating with Other Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

Hope this helps with your first issue, I may edit when I have more time to address #2.